# How to hide bootsrap grid systems' column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried this code:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I want to hide below `div` when in mobile phone view. Can I use media query or some thing else. Can we do it with bootstrap grid system ?

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
<div class="col-xs-4 hidden-xs" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
```

*and the below class names defined according to the width of device..*

**Extra small devices**
Phones (<768px) `(Class names : .visible-xs-block, hidden-xs)`

**Small devices**
Tablets (≥768px) `(Class names : .visible-sm-block, hidden-sm)`

**Medium devices**
Desktops (≥992px) `(Class names : .visible-md-block, hidden-md)`

**Large devices**
Desktops (≥1200px) `(Class names : .visible-lg-block, hidden-lg)`

For more information : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

You can add any of these conditional classes

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: thaks; i appled as :<div class=" col-sm-4 hidden-xs" style="background-color:red;">.col-sm-4</div>

Answer (score 0):

Use these classes to hide and show in corresponding devices

```
.visible-phone
.visible-tablet
.visible-desktop
.hidden-phone
.hidden-tablet
.hidden-desktop
```